# Problem with promises and mysql query return value

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am trying to implement a function which returns the value of a mysql query.
I try to use promises :

```js
query(query:string):string {
        var response = "No response ...";
        var sendrequest = (query:string):Promise<string> => {
            return new Promise( (resolve,reject) => {
                this.connection.query(query,  (err:string, result:string) => {
                    if (err) { reject(err); } else { resolve(result); }
                });
            });
        }

        sendrequest(query).then( (result:string) => {
            console.log("Résultat :" + result);
            return result;
        });
        return response;
    }
```

The result of the call is always "No response..." and I can't find how to solve it.
Can somebody help me please ?
Thanks a lot

Comment: That's because your method *is* actually returning "No response" no matter what.

Did you consider returning the promise instead and making your method async ?

Comment: You need either to return the promise itself or your function need to be async.

Comment: @crocarneiro async functions actually return a promise don't they ?

Comment: @36ve yeah you're right in the end the function would return a promise

Comment: I did not consider returning the promise itself and making the method async. How can I do that ? I mean, concerning the async. And where should I return the value of  the promise and how can I exctract the result of the query from it ?

Answer (score -1):

You can just return the promise itself.

```js
function query(query:string):Promise<string> {
        var sendrequest = (query:string):Promise<string> => {
            return new Promise( (resolve,reject) => {
                this.connection.query(query,  (err:string, result:string) => {
                    if (err) { reject(err); } else { resolve(result); }
                });
            });
        }

        return sendrequest;
    }
```

And then call your function like this:

```js
whateverImDoing = async() => {
   const result = await query("SELECT * FROM blablabla");
   // Do your thing with the result
}
```

Or like this:

```js
whateverImDoing = () => {
   query("SELECT * FROM blablabla").then(result => {
      // Do your thing with the result
   });
```

To better understand the concept you can try with this MRE:

```js
function getFirstTitle(query:string):Promise<string> {
    const myPromise = new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => resolve(json.title));
    });

    return myPromise;
}

getFirstTitle('teste').then((result:string) => console.log(result));
// "delectus aut autem"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, how can I use the result to return a string value, using the first method ?
whateverImDoing is supposed to be a string but here it is a promise

Comment: In both examples `result` will be a string I think

Comment: When I console.log result in the first method it prints a promise, and I can't use the second because I need to return a string

Comment: My bad. Updated the code, try with this now